# How to obtain ROC curves for Top-N classes in deep learning multi class classification cases using tensorflow. Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm a beginner in deep learning and **TensorFlow.keras (python)** and I have trained a **multi_class classification model using tf.keras in Co-Lab** . I have also obtained the graphs of other metrics such as Accuracy, Loss etc by Tensorboard. As ROC is not only for binary classification, I want to show the graphical plot that illustrates the diagnostic abilities of 60 Top classes of the model. I have trained the model to classify input sequences into **2982 classes** using batch-wise training. However, the model gives a good result for accuracy. Now it is important to **plot the ROC curves**. Please help me in this regard.

```
#isize=batch size
dataTest = np.zeros( (isize,1000,21), dtype=np.float32 )
labelsTest = np.zeros( (isize,2892), dtype=np.uint8 )
```

model input Layer

```
x_input = Input(shape=(1000, 21))
```

model compile and fit

```
import tensorflow.keras.metrics as tm



myadam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
    name='Adam'
)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=myadam, metrics=['accuracy',tm.Precision(),tm.Recall()])




training_generator =MyGenerator(rawDatasetLabel,rawDataset)
testing_generator=MyGenerator(rawTestDatasetLabel,rawTestDataset)

#callbacks

%mkdir logs
logdir='/content/logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)

class CustomModelCheckpoint(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
     self.model.save('FinalCOG2892_02.h5', overwrite=True)

cbk = CustomModelCheckpoint()
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',verbose=1,mode='min',patience=3)
mc = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)


EPOCHS =20
history = model.fit(training_generator,
                      epochs=EPOCHS,
                      verbose=1,
                      validation_data=testing_generator,callbacks=[cbk,tensorboard_callback,es,mc])
```

Training Results

```
Epoch 6/6
9258/9258 [==============================] - 3071s 332ms/step - loss: 0.4068 - accuracy: 0.9310 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9310 - precision_5: 0.9641 - recall_5: 0.9018 - val_loss: 0.3600 - val_accuracy: 0.9425 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9425 - val_precision_5: 0.9683 - val_recall_5: 0.9225
```

Now I want to draw ROC curve to top 60 classes, Please help.

Comment: please, someone, give me an idea?